# Which events have which achievements?

Tags: achievements, nintendo-land

In Nintendo Land, there are a bunch of 'achievements' you can get for doing well in different events. There are:

- Master Rank stars
- Trophies
- Stamps

All events in each attraction appear to have stamps. Which ones have trophies and master rank stars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping a Mii twice in the plaza gives an indication of that player's progress. This progress screen reveals a lot about what is available to achieve in the game.

[image: A player with 100% completion]

Here are all the possible things to achieve in the game. Master rank requirements are shown onscreen when picking the level. Trophies can be bronze, silver, gold, and platinum.

- The Legend of Zelda: Battle Quest

  - 10 Stamps
  - Master Rank on each level
  - Star Player
- Pikmin Adventure

  - 10 Stamps
  - Master Rank on each level
  - Star Player
- Metroid Blast

  - 15 Stamps
  - Master Rank on each level
  - Star Player
- Mario Chase

  - 5 Stamps
  - Star Player
- Luigi's Ghost Mansion

  - 5 Stamps
  - Star Player
- Animal Crossing Sweet Day

  - 5 Stamps
  - Star Player
- Yoshi's Fruit Cart

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player
- Octopus Dance

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player
- Donkey Kong Crash Course

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player
- Takamaru's Ninja Castle

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player
- Captain Falcon's Twister Race

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player
- Balloon Trip Breeze

  - 5 Stamps
  - Trophy
  - Star Player

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following give trophies:

- Octopus Dance
- Captain Falcon's Twister Race
- Ninja Castle

A continued list of trophies, stars, and stamps are on [this website.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/673043-nintendo-land/65187758)